# Poor performance of C++ function in Cython

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cython

I have this C++ function, which I can call from Python with the code below. The performance is only half compared to running pure C++. Is there a way to get their performance at the same level? I compile both codes with `-Ofast -march=native` flags. I do not understand where I can lose 50%, because most of the time should be spent in the C++ kernel. Is Cython making a memory copy that I can avoid?

```
namespace diff
{
    void diff_cpp(double* __restrict__ at, const double* __restrict__ a, const double visc,
                  const double dxidxi, const double dyidyi, const double dzidzi,
                  const int itot, const int jtot, const int ktot)
    {
        const int ii = 1;
        const int jj = itot;
        const int kk = itot*jtot;

        for (int k=1; k<ktot-1; k++)
            for (int j=1; j<jtot-1; j++)
                for (int i=1; i<itot-1; i++)
                {
                    const int ijk = i + j*jj + k*kk;
                    at[ijk] += visc * (
                            + ( (a[ijk+ii] - a[ijk   ]) 
                              - (a[ijk   ] - a[ijk-ii]) ) * dxidxi 
                            + ( (a[ijk+jj] - a[ijk   ]) 
                              - (a[ijk   ] - a[ijk-jj]) ) * dyidyi
                            + ( (a[ijk+kk] - a[ijk   ]) 
                              - (a[ijk   ] - a[ijk-kk]) ) * dzidzi
                            );
                }
    }
}
```

I have this `.pyx` file

```
# import both numpy and the Cython declarations for numpy
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

# declare the interface to the C code
cdef extern from "diff_cpp.cpp" namespace "diff":
    void diff_cpp(double* at, double* a, double visc, double dxidxi, double dyidyi, double dzidzi, int itot, int jtot, int ktot)

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def diff(np.ndarray[double, ndim=3, mode="c"] at not None,
         np.ndarray[double, ndim=3, mode="c"] a not None,
         double visc, double dxidxi, double dyidyi, double dzidzi):
    cdef int ktot, jtot, itot
    ktot, jtot, itot = at.shape[0], at.shape[1], at.shape[2]
    diff_cpp(&at[0,0,0], &a[0,0,0], visc, dxidxi, dyidyi, dzidzi, itot, jtot, ktot)
    return None
```

I call this function in Python

```
import numpy as np
import diff
import time

nloop = 20;
itot = 256;
jtot = 256;
ktot = 256;
ncells = itot*jtot*ktot;

at = np.zeros((ktot, jtot, itot))

index = np.arange(ncells)
a = (index/(index+1))**2
a.shape = (ktot, jtot, itot)

# Check results
diff.diff(at, a, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
print("at={0}".format(at.flatten()[itot*jtot+itot+itot//2]))

# Time the loop
start = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(nloop):
    diff.diff(at, a, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
end = time.perf_counter()

print("Time/iter: {0} s ({1} iters)".format((end-start)/nloop, nloop))
```

This is the `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

import numpy

setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension("diff",
                             sources=["diff.pyx"],
                             language="c++",
                             extra_compile_args=["-Ofast -march=native"],
                             include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])],
)
```

And here the C++ reference file that reaches twice the performance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include "math.h"

void init(double* const __restrict__ a, double* const __restrict__ at, const int ncells)
{
    for (int i=0; i<ncells; ++i)
    {
        a[i]  = pow(i,2)/pow(i+1,2);
        at[i] = 0.;
    }
}

void diff(double* const __restrict__ at, const double* const __restrict__ a, const double visc, 
          const double dxidxi, const double dyidyi, const double dzidzi, 
          const int itot, const int jtot, const int ktot)
{
    const int ii = 1;
    const int jj = itot;
    const int kk = itot*jtot;

    for (int k=1; k<ktot-1; k++)
        for (int j=1; j<jtot-1; j++)
            for (int i=1; i<itot-1; i++)
            {
                const int ijk = i + j*jj + k*kk;
                at[ijk] += visc * (
                        + ( (a[ijk+ii] - a[ijk   ]) 
                          - (a[ijk   ] - a[ijk-ii]) ) * dxidxi 
                        + ( (a[ijk+jj] - a[ijk   ]) 
                          - (a[ijk   ] - a[ijk-jj]) ) * dyidyi
                        + ( (a[ijk+kk] - a[ijk   ]) 
                          - (a[ijk   ] - a[ijk-kk]) ) * dzidzi
                        );
            }
}

int main()
{
    const int nloop = 20;
    const int itot = 256;
    const int jtot = 256;
    const int ktot = 256;
    const int ncells = itot*jtot*ktot;

    double *a  = new double[ncells];
    double *at = new double[ncells];

    init(a, at, ncells);

    // Check results
    diff(at, a, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, itot, jtot, ktot); 
    printf("at=%.20f\n",at[itot*jtot+itot+itot/2]);

    // Time performance 
    std::clock_t start = std::clock(); 

    for (int i=0; i<nloop; ++i)
        diff(at, a, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, itot, jtot, ktot); 

    double duration = (std::clock() - start ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("time/iter = %f s (%i iters)\n",duration/(double)nloop, nloop);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does your c++ testing code look like? And maybe setup-file?

Comment: @ead. I added both.

Comment: It may be a typo, but `nloop` in your C++ source is half that in your Python source, 10 vs 20. That could certainly explain a factor of two performance difference.

Comment: @bnaecker. You are correct, but I divide benchmark time by `nloop`, so that does not explain the difference. I changed it nonetheless, thanks!

Comment: @Chiel Right you are. What about the `#pragma ivdep`? Could be vectorization by the compiler in the pure C++ case. Have you tried removing that and comparing?

Comment: @bnaecker. That is a flag for the intel compiler which I am not using in these tests. Removed it now, to avoid confusion...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is not what is happening during the run, but which optimization is happening during the compilation.

Which optimization is done depends on the compiler (or even version) and there is no guarantee that every optimization, which can be done will be done.

Actually there are two different reasons why cython is slower, depending on whether you use g++ or clang++:

- g++ is unable to optimize due to flag `-fwrapv` in the cython build
- clang++ is unable to optimize in the first place (read on to see what happens).

---

**First issue (g++)**: Cython compiles with different flags compared to the flags of your pure c++-program and as result some optimizations can't be done.

If you look at the log of the setup, you will see:

```
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc ... -O2 ..-fwrapv .. -c diff.cpp ... -Ofast -march=native
```

As you told, `-Ofast` will win against `-O2`because it comes last. But the problem is `-fwrapv`, which seems to prevent some optimization, as signed integer overflow cannot be considered UB and used for optimization any longer.

So you have following options:

- add `-fno-wrapv` to `extra_compile_flags`, the disadvantage is, that all files are now compiled with changed flags, what might be unwanted.
- build a library from cpp with only flags you like and link it to your cython module. This solution has some overhead, but has the advantage of being robust: as you pointed out for different compilers different cython-flags could be the problem - so the first solution might be too brittle.
- not sure you can disable default flags, but maybe there is some information in docs.

---

**Second issue (clang++)** inlining in the test cpp-program.

When I compile your cpp-program with my pretty old 5.4-version g++:

```
 g++ test.cpp -o test -Ofast -march=native -fwrapv
```

it becomes almost 3-times slower compared to the compilation without `-fwrapv`. This is however a weakness of the optimizer: When inlining, it should see, that no signed-integer overflow is possible (all dimensions are about `256`), so the flag `-fwrapv` shouldn't have any impact.

My old `clang++`-version (3.8) seems to do a better job here: with the flags above I cannot see any degradation of the performance. I need to disable inlining via `-fno-inline` to become a slower code but it is slower even without `-fwrapv` i.e.:

```
 clang++ test.cpp -o test -Ofast -march=native -fno-inline
```

So there is a systematical bias in favor of your c++-program: the optimizer can optimize the code for the known values after the inlining - something the cython can not do.

So we can see: clang++ was not able to optimize `function diff` with arbitrary sizes but was able to optimize it for size=256. Cython however, can only use the not optimized version of `diff`. That is the reason, why `-fno-wrapv` has no positive impact.

My take-away from it: disallow inlining of the function of interest (e.g. compile it in its own object file) in the cpp-tester to ensure a level ground with cython, otherwise one sees performance of a program which was specially optimized for this one input.

---

NB: A funny thing is, that if all `int`s are replaced by `unsigned int`s, then naturally `-fwrapv` doesn't play any role, but the version with `unsigned int` is as slow as `int`-version with `-fwrapv`, which is only logical, as there is no undefined behavior to be exploited.

Comment: The last flag wins, as far as I know, otherwise it is impossible to override if the flags are already set.

Comment: @Chiel OK, you are right, but there is something in the other flags that interfere with the optimization - the assemblies are pretty different for files compiled via cython and directly with g++

Comment: This is not true. If I compile the fast c++ code with all the flags that come the Cython compilation, then I still reproduce the performance difference. Can you reproduce the difference?

Comment: @Chiel With `g++ test.cpp -o test -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -ftrapv -Ofast -march=native`- 0.20 seconds

Comment: @Chiel the same without `-fwrapv`: 0.07 seconds

Comment: Shouldn't `-ftrapv` anyhow not override `-fwrapv`? I don't find any differences in the speed of my Cython code, unfortunately.

Comment: @Chiel `-ftrapv` overrides `-ftrapw` but now `-ftrapv` prevents the optimization. My line in setup is `extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11', '-Ofast', '-march=native', '-fno-wrapv']`  and I get exact the same speed as with cpp

Comment: Interesting. I do reach good results with gcc, but not with clang, where the Cython version is still slower

Comment: @Chiel I see, I copied a wrong line with `-ftrapv` sorry for confusion - '-ftrapv` is not from cython, but I tried to use it first...

Comment: @Chiel if it is so brittle, I would build a (static) library with my cpp and with flags I like and link it to the cython module. You don't really need inlining here...

Comment: @Chiel I think I found explanation, why clang++ is slower - it was never fast in the first place, please take a look at my updated answer for more info

Comment: That is a great piece of research. I reproduce it. If I retrieve the dimensions as a command line parameter I have identical speeds. Awesome. Thanks a lot!