# Need a fresh perspective on recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I just can't wrap my head around this.

Why do these two functions produce radically different results,

when line 4 seems identical?


**Version I**

```
int factorial(int val) // input=5; output=120
{
    if (val != 0)
        return factorial(val - 1) * val;
    return 1;
}
```

**Version II**

```
int factorial(int val) // input=5; output=0
{
    if (val != 0)
        return factorial(--val) * val;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `val - 1` doesn't affect the variable `val`, but with `--val` you have a decrement on `val`

Comment: Get familiar with the concept of a "stack frame".

Comment: This is the type of problem that's pretty easy to check when you step through it in your debugger.

Comment: Using a variable whose value is auto incremented/decremented in the same expression results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @MrEricSir: Not really. The debugger doesn't tell you when your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Lightness Yes the debugger won't flag UB. But since the UB in this case does behave consistently on OP's compiler. If OP had stepped through the code with a debugger, OP should see that `factorial(1)` is evaluated as `factorial(0) * 0` ... Which is the point MrEricSir was making.

Comment: @CraigYoung: _"the UB in this case does behave consistently on OP's compiler"_ You do not know that until you have tested it on the OP's compiler infinite times.

Comment: @CraigYoung: _"Which is the point MrEricSir was making."_ Yes I understood the point, which was to foster an incorrect understanding both of this program and of the constructions at play here.

Comment: @Lightness I often see 2 extreme misinterpretations of UB, at opposite ends of the spectrum. 1) Too optimistic: "I observed x behaviour in a few simple cases, I can assume UB behaves as x" (_obviously not_) 2) Too pessimistic: "UB means the compiler might eat your cat" (_again, obviously not_). The point is, barring actual bugs in the compiler: the compiler may generate machine code that exhibits UB, but the compiler itself does not exhibit UB. Therefore given particular input the compiler will always output the _same binaries_.

Comment: OP's compiler evidently decrements `val` ***before*** performing the multiplication given OP's source code. Obviously a change to _input_ (such as optimisation settings) may change the compiler's output. But the simple fact is that this ***most certainly is*** something OP could have debugged to observe ***why*** his program was behaving unexpectedly. (Though obviously that wouldn't help OP understand that his code would exhibit UB.)

Comment: @CraigYoung: _"Therefore given particular input the compiler will always output the same binaries."_ That's an unfounded assumption, and it's not extreme to say so. The rest makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They only seem identical if you don't read them - one says `val - 1` and the other says `--val`.

- `val - 1`: Subtraction. Evaluates to the value of `val`, minus one
- `--val`: Decrement. Reduces `val` by one, and evaluates to the new value

The latter example has undefined behaviour because you try to read `val` again on the same line.

Comment: I downvoted for the original answer,`They only seem identical if you don't read them - one says val - 1 and the other says --val`, as this was quite obvious that it was being asked about the functional difference between the two. With the edit, I have removed my downvote.

Comment: @Thebluefish: You must be on 56k, with the answer trickling through really slowly like loading a full-screen GIF in the 1990s... ;)

Comment: It would appear to be so ;)

Comment: To reaffirm - the radically different results come because the second program has undefined behaviour. Any further analysis is mathematically impossible.

Comment: Plus one for mentioning UB

Comment: _If_ this weren't UB, and _if_ the compiler chose to evaluate the decrement first then you end up with a string of multiplications ending in 0 (`var == 1`, `--var`, `return factorial(0) * 0`) which will then get passed up to the top level. In an alternate universe somewhere, that's why the OP observed the result 0. In this universe, though, it's just because the program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: You don't need to invoke UB to see what the difference is between `--var` and `var - 1`.

Comment: @immibis: No, you don't, but the OP is invoking it regardless, in _this_ program that is being asked about.

Answer (score 4):

Version 2 changes the value of val via the `--val`, where version 1 only subtracts 1 from val but doesn't update the value of val when doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Use of

```
return factorial(--val) * val;
```

is cause for undefined behavior. Don't use it.

For evaluating the expression, the compiler is free to evaluate `factorial(--val)` first, then evaluate `val`, and then perform the multiplication. It is also free to evaluate `val` first, then evaluate `factorial(--val)`, and then perform the multiplication.

If the compiler chooses the first strategy, that statement is equivalent to:

```
--val;
return factorial(val)*val;
```

As you can see, that is incorrect.

If the compiler chooses the second strategy, that statement is equivalent to:

```
int res = factorial(val-1)*val;
--val
return res;
```

Had the compiler followed this strategy, you'd have gotten the correct answer.

---

OTOH, the statment

```
return factorial(val-1)*val;
```

does not suffer from that problem and always returns the correct value.

Comment: It is free to fry some fish then atomise it and spread the molecules in an uneven distribution about the Pleiades constellation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, among other things.

Comment: Indeed. Seriously, don't underestimate [the bizarre potential that UB has](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48731306/560648); there are _way_ more than two possible results here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, no kidding. The crap that optimizers can spring on you is something I am nowhere near familiar with.

Comment: @Lightness "_It is free to fry some fish then atomise it and spread the molecules in an uneven distribution about the Pleiades constellation._" Utter rubbish. Stop being alarmist. Incredulous claims just reduce credibility. Yes you're emphasising that you have absolutely no guarantees about what might or might not happen, but that's not going to make the compiler violate the laws of physics! This blinkered view seems to have made you lose sight of the ***fact*** that OP _could have_ debugged his program to observe what his compiler _actually **did do**_ with his code.

Comment: @CraigYoung: It's not a "blinkered view", it is a robust and rigourous view that will lead to robust and rigourous code. Lern2abstract